# define max and min length for angucomplete-alt directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, autocomplete

I'm developing an angularjs application, within i have used angucomplete-alt directive for the first time. Thus, i'm wondering about how can i specify the size of the directive's value whatever min or max, it doesn't matter so far. I checked the documentation and I didn't find it.
Is there anyone's familiar with this directive give me a tricky way to deal with value's length?.

Answer (score 0):

But there are `minlength` and `maxlength` properties in documentation

https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt#description-of-attributes

How did you miss it?

Answer (score 0):

they talk about the length of the input for the search process not the authorized size which i need as a rule for my form validation.